# Swift UIView blinks during changing alpha

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview

I have a problem with changing opacity for UIView. I am changing it this way: UIView.alpha = value. If I change it with step = 0.01 - the view blinks. i.e. view with alpha=0.05 may be less visible than view with alpha=0.04. I change alpha with step=0.01 and the result may be: view visible better->better->worse->better->worse etc. I do not understand why it is happens. It is the same for simulator and real device. The project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5cO_tAtLPiwcFk2Qk4wbldDT3M/view?usp=sharing
Also I animated the changing alpha from 0.0 to 1.0 during 20 sec:  youtu.be/in34amFvyOE

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var alpha = CGFloat()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        LableA.alpha = 0
        AlphaLabel.text = "Alpha: \(alpha)"
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var LableA: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var AlphaLabel: UILabel!
    @IBAction func pressedChAlphaBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
        alpha = alpha + 0.01
        LableA.alpha = alpha
        print(alpha)
        AlphaLabel.text = "Alpha: \(alpha)"
    }
    @IBAction func pressedResetBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
        alpha = 0
        LableA.alpha = alpha
        print(alpha)
        AlphaLabel.text = "Alpha: \(alpha)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide your code in the question itself?

Comment: We are not here to debug your project. You will have to create a minimum reproducible example of your problem and include it in your question.

Comment: I do not ask you to debug the project. The attached project is a simple project just to show how the alpha changes. I have created it for you guys. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Animate the change:

Swift 1, 2

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) {
    self.LableA.alpha = alpha
}
```

Swift 3

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
    self.LableA.alpha = alpha
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. But I already tried to use animation here. It does not help. As I understand, the problem in the final value of alpha/opacity. Do you guys have any ideas? Thanks!